# pgfplot - ylabel on the right

Tags: tikz-pgf

as much as I know, the following code should have the y axis label on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread{Example.txt} \mytable
  \begin{axis} [ ytick pos=right,
                 ylabel near ticks,
                 ylabel={Bla}, ]
    \addplot table [x index=0, y index=1] {\mytable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where 'Example.txt' is just
        0             2
        1             2
        2             2
        3             2
        4             1
(With line breaks, they just don't appear here)
Unfortunately the y-label still appears on the left. What did I make wrong?

Thanks,
   Juhui

Comment: Which version of `pgfplots` are you using? Your example code works as expected in my system (TeX Live2012, pgf version 2.10, pgfplots.sty: 2011/12/29 v1.5.1.).

Comment: Hi Medina, thanks for your reply. It pushed me into the right direction. Something is wrong with my installation. For now, I updated my ubuntu packages and I'm still not at pgfplots version 1.3, but at least now it works. Thanks a lot,

Comment: You're welcome! You should consider installing TeX Live from [TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/); the official repos ship a really old LaTeX system. Since you're problems has been solved, this question will perhaps be closed as too localized.